# MySQL - What's the best way to perform this operation

Tags: mysql, select, distinct, min

i've a table like:

```
| ID | value |
|  0 |   5   |
|  1 |   2   |
|  0 |   1   |
|  1 |   6   |
|  2 |   3   |
|  2 |   8   |
|  1 |   2   |
|  0 |   1   |
|  2 |   4   |
```

I'm trying to take in my result only one row for id where value is the min of all the column, something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table WHERE MIN(table.value) = table.value
```

how can i solve? thanks!

EDIT:

My desired output is:

```
| ID | value |
|  0 |   1   | -> is the min of all the rows with id = 0
|  1 |   2   |
|  2 |   3   |
```

EDIT 2:

Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tableName AS A
WHERE value = (SELECT MIN(value) From tableName AS B WHERE A.ID=B.ID)
```

But tableName is `(SELECT * FROM ...........)`.. how can i perform?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Value
FROM tableName
WHERE value = (SELECT MIN(value) From tableName)
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f174e3/1)

follow-up question, what happens if there are same lowest `value` with different `ID`, what record will be shown?

Comment: sorry man.. in this way it gives me only one row with taking the id that has min value in all the table.. i need to take for every id the min value of id group.. something like.. id = 0 = >row = 3. take id = 0 where row = min(row). id = 1 = >row = 6. take id=1 where row = min(row)

Comment: i get, i was confused of this `only ONE ROW for id where value is the min of ALL the column`. i will just update the answer.

Comment: @JackTurky can you post your desired output on your question?

Comment: ok updated my question.. sorry but my english is not very good ( as you can see ) :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, a.value
FROM tableName AS a
WHERE a.value = (SELECT MIN(b.value)
                 FROM tableName AS b
                 WHERE a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: if my tableName is a result of another subquery?

Comment: just replace tableName with `(select from ... )` with the parantheses included

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want

```
select id,min(value) from tableName group by id
```